# Pdf export freeze when i try to export it

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, dompdf, export-to-pdf

So i'm trying to implement a PDF export. I installed dompdf with composer, i put "'PDF' => Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade::class" in aliases and "Barryvdh\DomPDF\ServiceProvider::class" in providers in config/app.php. On my route i have this code:

```
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::get('/users/{userId}/details/{forReport}/exportPDF', function($userId) {
    $user = UserHelper::getUser($userId);
    $internal_devices = UserHelper::getUsersAssignedInternalDevices($userId);
    $external_devices = UserHelper::getUsersAssignedExternalDevices($userId);
    $licenses = UserHelper::getUsersAssignedLicenses($userId);
    $delegation_devices = UserHelper::getUsersDevicesOnDelegation($userId);
    $pdf = PDF::loadView(URLHelper::userReportView(),
        [
        'user' => $user,
        'internal_devices' => $internal_devices,
        'external_devices' => $external_devices,
        'licenses' => $licenses,
        'delegation_devices' => $delegation_devices,
    ]);
    return $pdf->download('My.pdf');
})->name('admin.exportPDF');
```

When i call this route, i get execution time-out and i have 300 seconds. In conclusion, PDF is not generated. Is something wrong with my code?

PS: i did a var_damp and everything looks alright

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Have you checked whether there might be tons of data written to the PDF?

Comment: There is a few amount of data, but i expect it to work because i want this pdf to work dynamically

Comment: It's okay to expect that, but if there is too much data to be processed within a given time limit, you have to check your possibilities. If there is too much data involved, try to check whether the generation runs faster with less data. If so, you have to optimize the generation by this terms. If not, you can at least exclude that. Nevertheless: you could set a higher time limit and profile your application using XDebug or Blackfire, which would point you to the slow parts

Comment: right now i have only like 3 objects that are placed in the web page so it's really few data. I don't expect it to take so long. I even tried to put only the attributes of the user and again, i get the same error

Comment: Well, then you need to start debugging